# Sentinel2 pixel values and grayscales in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, rasterio, sentinel-2, pixel, rioxarray

My goal is to get the Sentinel-2 pixel values and coordinates.

So I used python `rioxarray_open.rasterio` to load the Sentinel2 pixels values and plot the results in QGIS.

```
pixel_value = rioxarray.open_rasterio("root/32DPD_20220101T102431_B04.jp2")
pixel_value = pixel_value.squeeze()
gdf_pixel_value = pixel_value.to_dataframe().reset_index()
```

For testing, I just load a sub-region of the band - 100*100pixels. The result I got was promising, with 10,000 values (digital numbers). But after I plot it in QGIS, it is strange. Different values should have different grayscales/colors, but you could see that every four neighbor pixels are exactly the same color.

I changed the symbology with “unique value” to better distinguish the grayscales. Now you can clearly see that four different pixels share the same color:

Why would this happen?

[image]

Comment: hi Bera, thanks for the quick reply! I updated my question to make it clear. My goal is to get the Sentinel pixel values. And since I wanna do this for many Sentinel bands so I use python for this purpose.

Comment: Sentinel-2 bands do not all have the same spatial resolution. So could it be that you are looking at data from a coarser band that has been resampled?

Comment: @ChloeG I check the original/unprocessed Sentinel data and measure its individual pixel, and found out that, for 10m resolution bands, the pixels shown in QGIS are 20m long... It seems like it's the problem from the Sentinel bands themselves.

Comment: Maybe it would help to kno where you downloaded the Sentinel-2 data? I think it comes in different formats depending on the provider. For instance, from the sentinelsat API, the data comes in SAFE format, which contains several versions. A 10m version that contains only high-resolution bands (2,3,4 and 8). A 20m version, which contains the 20m-resolution bands (7, 8a, 11 and 12), and the downsampled high-res bands. And finally a 60m version, which contains all bands, with the higher res downsampled to 60m.